# how do I Columns to x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

Please help i am trying to make all then columns into x-axis and the make side by side bars later by date

this is my data i really tried but to no avail

```
    dateVisited hh_visited hh_ind_confirmed new_in_mig out_mig deaths HOH_death Preg_Obs Preg_Outcome child_forms
102  2020-07-21        292             1170        131      86     18         7        3           14          79
103  2020-07-22        400             1553        115     100     25        10       11           18         107
104  2020-07-23        381             1458        103      67     21         9        5           23          87
105  2020-07-24        345             1379         90      98     12         4        3           20          89
106  2020-07-25        436             1585        131     119     13         2        7           20         117
107  2020-07-26          0                0          0       0      0         0        0    

    0           0
```

Comment: Provide reproducible example data, and show some effort code.

Comment: hi i know it seems like laziness for not producing code i understand where you are coming from i fairly new here so my code was even far from the produces answer will keep leaning even study the answer further will come up with better questions even answers in the future thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -1) %>%
  ggplot(aes(name, value)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = dateVisited), width = 0.6, 
           position = position_dodge(width = 0.8)) +
  guides(x = guide_axis(angle = 45))
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible Data from question**

```r
df <- structure(list(dateVisited = structure(1:6, .Label = c("2020-07-21", 
"2020-07-22", "2020-07-23", "2020-07-24", "2020-07-25", "2020-07-26"
), class = "factor"), hh_visited = c(292L, 400L, 381L, 345L, 
436L, 0L), hh_ind_confirmed = c(1170L, 1553L, 1458L, 1379L, 1585L, 
0L), new_in_mig = c(131L, 115L, 103L, 90L, 131L, 0L), out_mig = c(86L, 
100L, 67L, 98L, 119L, 0L), deaths = c(18L, 25L, 21L, 12L, 13L, 
0L), HOH_death = c(7L, 10L, 9L, 4L, 2L, 0L), Preg_Obs = c(3L, 
11L, 5L, 3L, 7L, 0L), Preg_Outcome = c(14L, 18L, 23L, 20L, 20L, 
0L), child_forms = c(79L, 107L, 87L, 89L, 117L, 0L)), class = "data.frame",
row.names = c("102", "103", "104", "105", "106", "107"))
```

Comment: Thank  you very much it worked, as it seems like i did no put enough effort on the code(which was far from yours), i pretty new there are some fictions(%>%) that i'm still getting familiar with, i will study your answer and would come with better questions in the future thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your data cannot be used easily since it requires time to format it into something that could ingested by `R`. Here is something to get you started. I made up a hypothetical dataframe of 4 columns that resemble your data, use the function `melt` from `reshape2` package to format the data such that it is understandable by `ggplot2` package, and use `ggplot2` package to generate a bar plot.

```
df <- data.frame(dateVisited = seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), as.Date('2019-12-31'), 30),
                 hh_visited = runif(13, 0, 436),
                 hh_ind_confirmed = runif(13, 0, 1585),
                 new_in_mig = runif(13, 0, 131))

df <- reshape2::melt(df, id.vars = 'dateVisited')

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = dateVisited, y = value, fill = variable))+
  geom_col(position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: Thanks you very much, i will look closely at the breakdown and study it there is the runif() that i need to understand thank you, i'll get ti it

Comment: Your welcome @Selamola Tloubatla! `runif` is just to generate n uniformly distributed data. For example  `runif(13, 0, 131)` will generate `13` data point between `0` and `131` (assuming a uniform distribution). Also you may want to look at `dput` function, so that the next time you want to ask a question, people can easily access your data to help you solve your problem. Basically, you do `dput (your_data)` and copy/paste the output. In addition, the tradition is that you should accept / upvote answers that have helped you solve your problem.